# Admin site for custom user model and extended user model

Tags: django

My Django app needs custom user model and some additional fields so I have defined them as below:

**Custom User Model and Manager** (defined in an app called `users`):

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):

    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

**Extra model field** (defined in an app called `api`):

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**The Admin Site** (defined in `users` app):

```
class CustomerInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Customer
    readonly_fields = ('created',)


@admin.register(CustomUser)
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):

    inlines = (CustomerInline,)

    list_display = ('email', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser')

    list_filter = ('email', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser')

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name')}),
        (
            ('Permissions'),
            {
                'fields': (
                    'is_active',
                    'is_staff',
                    'is_superuser',
                    'groups',
                    'user_permissions',
                )
            },
        ),
    )

    add_fieldsets = (
        (
            None,
            {
                'classes': ('wide',),
                'fields': (
                    'email',
                    'password1',
                    'password2',
                    'is_active',
                    'is_staff',
                    'is_superuser',
                ),
            },
        ),
    )

    search_fields = ('email',)

    ordering = ('email',)
```

Admin site works almost fine except that nothing is shown for `created` field while it must show the date of creation of the user.

I know that Django has `date_joined` and I may use that instead. The issue is why my inline is not working properly.

[image]

Comment: The only other field than `created` is `user`, and that will be filled in automatically since that deals with the `user` you are creating/editing...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem My question is about ```created``` field. It must contain the date of creation, but what I see is just a dash (see the screenshot).

Comment: at the time of the creation, the value is not filled in *yet*, that will normally be done when you save the object...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I create the user inside ```admin``` site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Customer` is not created together with the `CustomUser` automatically. What you see in the admin is just form for adding new Customer with all fields readonly. Once you save it I assume the Customer gets created as well. You should handle it though in the scenarios where the goal is to have CustomUser always have Customer attached. You can either put it directly to the place CustomUsers are created, e.g. admin, registration, etc. Or use signal on CustomUser creation that creates Customer as well.

Comment: I create a user inside ```admin``` site and the ```created``` field is set to ```auto_now_add``` so I assume that means when I click on the ```save``` button in the user creation form of ```admin``` site ```created``` field should be populated but even after editing the user (entering first name etc) that field is still empty.

Comment: Is the Customer model instance created though? When you check the database or register Customer admin too.

Comment: I removed the inline and registered Customer in Admin site, and it's EMPTY !

Comment: So as I mention in the answer you need to handle OneToOneField creation. OneToOneField is basically a ForeignKey with some constraints but the objects are not created automatically. ForeignKey allows you to add to the relationship in admin manually but in your case it would be better to handle it in the code.